# Headless Chrome Puppeteer: Page to tell Puppeteer that it's ready

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to create a PDF of a page that has many external AJAX requests.

```
await page.goto(url);
const buffer = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4' })
```

I have tried `waitUntil:'networkidle0'` and various other `waits`, but nothing other than a time delay is enough to capture the loaded data.

So now I'm trying to get the page to tell Puppeteer that it's ready, but can't see how from the docs.

Ideally, I want the page to trigger an event, and Puppeteer to wait for it, like this:

```
await page.goto(url);
await page.on('readyForPdf');
const buffer = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4' })
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [`page.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) to wait for the last element that you are expecting to load.

Example Usage:

```
await page.goto( 'https://www.example.com/', { waitUntil : 'networkidle0' } );

await page.waitForSelector( '#last-expected-element' );

const buffer = await page.pdf({
    path   : 'page.pdf',
    format : 'A4'
});
```

Comment: Trouble is he may not know the order that the `AJAX` requests come back in.

Comment: @Rippo Use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait until multiple async processes are complete.